# cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED while using flair

Tags: pytorch

I have been using https://github.com/zalandoresearch/flair#example-usage

tried using flair to experiment flair but then I don't know why I am  not able to use the GPU.
and tried the following:

```
>>> from flair.data import Sentence
>>> from flair.models import SequenceTagger
>>> sentence = Sentence('I love Berlin .')
>>> tagger = SequenceTagger.load('ner')
2019-07-20 17:52:15,062 loading file /home/vz/.flair/models/en-ner-conll03-v0.4.pt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vz/miniconda3/envs/gp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flair/nn.py", line 103, in load
    model = cls._init_model_with_state_dict(state)
  File "/home/vz/miniconda3/envs/gp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flair/models/sequence_tagger_model.py", line 205, in _init_model_with_state_dict
    locked_dropout=use_locked_dropout,
  File "/home/vz/miniconda3/envs/gp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flair/models/sequence_tagger_model.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.to(flair.device)
  File "/home/vz/miniconda3/envs/gp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 386, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "/home/vz/miniconda3/envs/gp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 193, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/vz/miniconda3/envs/gp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 193, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/home/vz/miniconda3/envs/gp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 193, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/home/vz/miniconda3/envs/gp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 127, in _apply
    self.flatten_parameters()
  File "/home/vz/miniconda3/envs/gp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 123, in flatten_parameters
    self.batch_first, bool(self.bidirectional))
RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
```

Can anyone please help me as to how to fix this error ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is with my machine and CUDNN requirement i would suggest every one to install pytorch with conda so the way to install should be something like this

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch
```

to Eradicate any kind of issues with the installation.

Comment: You can find the correct statement for your platform in (Install PyTorch) https://pytorch.org/